Can I set "Smallest Width" Per app?
I use my device with a different Smallest Width setting (600 instead of default 400 something). it makes everything better for me EXCEPT it totally ruins the scaling of one or two apps. Is there any way to change this setting or otherwise fix the scaling just for these apps?

I don't believe so. You have to either select a recognised resolution in the settings, or bear with the odd errors.
